# How can I check if a value is in a comma seperated list?

Tags: jquery

This is the output of my variable `docNames`:

```
test3,test1
```

The output of my variable `value` is:

```
test
```

Now I want to check if `test` is in the list.
My approach:

```
var inList = docNames.indexOf(value) != -1;
```

But the output I get is `TRUE`. This is actually not what I want. Because only `test1` and `test3` should be true to be in the list, not `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string by its delimiter and see if the resulting array [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the value:

```js
var docNames = 'test3,test1';
var value = 'test';
var inList = docNames.split(',').includes(value);
console.log(inList);
```

Answer (score 1):

To really check if there is value in the string you can do `.split` and to check optional spaces before and after the value as well in the string.

Read more about `.split` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
var docNames = 'test3,test1';
var split = docNames.split(/\s*,\s*/);
var hasValue = split.indexOf('test') > -1;
console.log(hasValue)
```